# Can I manage my own domain using a web sever at home without having a static IP address using NO-IP?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, home-server, dynamic-dns

I have purchased my own domain in GoDaddy.
I have a server at home, Windows Server 2008 R2 to be specific.
I do not have a static IP address, however I have created an account in No-IP, have the DUC software running which assures that the hostname I was provided with will always point to the dynamic IP address at my place.

However, in GoDaddy they ask for an IP to specify where is the site hosted. How can I do this?

Comment: I moved my DNS to [ZoneEdit.com](http://zoneedit.com). It supports dynamic DNS, so every couple hours a script runs on my PC to update the IP address with zoneedit. In 5+ years I've been able to host my web site and manage the machines on my home network without issue.

Comment: So, your suggestion would be for me to move from GoDaddy to ZoneEdit? Is this easy to do?

Comment: Yes, but you should check it out for yourself.  ZoneEdit's help system will educate you

Comment: Great, I could make it work with DavidSchwartz post, but this would have probably been my alternative plan. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point sub-domains at your dynamic DNS name using CNAME records. However, you cannot point the base of the domain itself without using a proxy.

So if your domain is `example.com`, you can make `www.example.com` work just by adding a `CNAME` for `www` to your dynamic DNS name.

GoDaddy's offers a redirection service. Say your domain is `example.com`. To make  `http://example.com` work (without a `www`) use GoDaddy's HTTP proxy service to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`. You'll need an `A` record for `example.com` that points to GoDaddy's redirection service.

Comment: Im trying this as we speak. I just changed the CNAME records, it takes a while to update. I'll come back as soon as I have a result! Thankss

Comment: I could make this work for the `www.example.com`. However, I tried adding an A record that points to GoDaddy's redirection service and forwarding example.com to `http://www.example.com`. The GoDaddy redirection service I found is this one: `64.202.189.170`. But I am not quite sure if this is correct, because it is not working. Have you got any idea why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "It is not working" is not a helpful problem description. What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: Sorry! It wasn't a helpful description at all but your answer was. I thought it wasn't working because I was checking the response of each url from the cmd making a ping for `www.example.com` and for `example.com` but `example.com` was not answering. When you answer with no specific comment on what I was doing I opened a browser and test each url, it was working fine. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the already helpful answers, here's confirmation from GoDaddy that as of 1 week ago (May 2012) they do not directly support dynamic DNS:

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/domains-management-and-services/forum/topic/dynamic-ip-1/

Sounds like you would be best off migrating your domain to another company. If you like No-IP they can handle a domain with a dynamic IP if you sign up for a paid No-IP Plus account. See more details here:

http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/plus_dynamic_dns.html

Comment: He doesn't need them to support dynamic DNS since he already has a dynamic DNS server that's working.

Comment: Right, I just said that it doesn't _directly_ support dynamic DNS and in my opinion it's just easier to do the whole setup through a company that does. Your answer is a perfectly valid option as well of course.

Answer (score 2):

> However, in GoDaddy they ask for an IP to specify where is the site hosted. How can I do this?

Since GoDaddy hosts your DNS for you, they want to know where to point DNS. If you use a Dynamic DNS service you will need to move your DNS to them.

More info: https://serverfault.com/questions/234625/godaddy-hosting-with-dynamic-ip

Comment: My IP address at home changes (at least) every 12 hours. So sadly thats not a choice. Thanks for pointing out that mistake, I meant to say "I do not have a STATIC ip address"

Answer (score 1):

If you point your NS (name servers) from GoDaddy, to your No-ip address, then that should work. 
Say Example.com is your domain and Example.no-ip.org is your No-Ip address
then in godaddy's control panel change your name servers to example.no-ip.org
then in windows dns on your server, set up a new forwards zone for your ip, then add an A record for www with the ip being your current dynamic ip.   Every time your ip changes you will have to alter this A record, put you shouldn't have to alter your settings for godaddy